# Как в ListFragment в элементах списка перед текстом поставить изображение?

Tags: java, android

У меня имеется Navigation Drawer Activity. Вот оно, на картинке ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я нажимаю на элемент в списке, меня перекидывает на ListFragment. Он на картинке ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И мне надо на местах, где находятся красные полосочки расположить изображения, при чем в каждом элементе меню нужно чтобы они были разные.
Подскажите как это сделать.
Код ListFragment:

```
package fragments;


import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class Name_ListFragment extends ListFragment
{
String dataname[] = new String[]{"name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "name6", "name7"};

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataname);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

Comment: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html
что-то плохо ищете

Comment: простейший запрос дает [огромное количество](http://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&q=android+listview+with+image) вариантов решения. Чтобы здесь вам подсказали, как такое реализовать в вопросе недостаточно данных (в частности, что за картинки, где находятся, как связаны с текстом и тд)

Comment: @pavlofff, я указал более точные данные. Взгляните пожалуйста.

Comment: ни на один из действительно важных для решения вашей проблемы вопросов так и не получил ответа (смотрите комментарий выше)

Comment: @pavlofff, картинки расположены в drawable, размером 24x24(обычные векторные картинки). Названия картинок для каждого элемента списка последовательно: dot.png, info.png, command.png, cube.png, spider.png. lock.png, earth.png. С текстом они никак не связаны(просто лежат в папке drawable). У меня просто имеется Navigation Drawer Activity и несколько ListFragment. Конечно, может быть и сейчас не дан полный ответ, я не давно начал учится создавать приложения под Android, просто моя задача понять как расположить изображения в элементах списка ListFragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое решение:

Во первых, нужно создать разметку айтема, так как андроид не предлагает по умолчанию таких разметок с картинкой. Она будет определять, как будет выглядеть каждый элемент списка. Назовем ее `list_item.xml` и поместим в папку *res/layout/* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Здесь важно, что ID виджетов `image1` (то, куда будет выводиться картинка) и `text1` (то, куда будет выводиться текст) нужно запомнить, они нам пригодятся в дальнейшем.

Сам класс фрагмента:

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment{

    //Заполняем данные. Имена и соответствующие им картинки в двух массивах
    String dataname[] = new String[]{"name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "name6", "name7"};
    int images[] = new int[]{R.drawable.dot, R.drawable.info, R.drawable.command, R.drawable.cube, R.drawable.spider, R.drawable.lock, R.drawable.earth};

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        //создаем карту данных для адаптера
        List<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        // Заполняем ее данными
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
            hm.put("keyText", dataname[i]);
            hm.put("keyImage", Integer.toString(images[i]) );
            list.add(hm);
        }

        //Здесь указываем по каким ключам карты получать данные
        String[] from = {"keyImage","keyText"};

        //Здесь указываем ID виджетов на нашей разметке, в которые помещать эти данные
        int[] to = {R.id.image1, R.id.text1};

        //в адаптере указываем разметку айтема, саму карту данных, откуда брать данные и куда помещать
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list, R.layout.list_item, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```